# Regex in Unix shell script

Tags: regex, string, shell, unix

I need to match the file name with pattern "myTestData_[YYYYMMDD]*[HHMMSS]*[NNN].csv.gz". Sample matching file name is "myTestData_20140821_052354_001.csv.gz"

Here `myTestData_` and `.csv.gz` are constants and YYYYMMDD & HHMMSS are from timestamp. NNN is any 3 digit number. Could you please advise what should be my regex pattern in Unix script.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
infile='fileNameSamples.csv'
while read line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^myTestData_\d{8}_\d{6}_\d{3}.csv.gz$ ]] ; then
        echo 'matched:'$line
      else
        echo 'failed'
    fi
done < "$infile"
```

Here are the file names in fileNameSamples.csv:

```
myTestData_20140821_001.csv.gz
TestData_20140821_001.csv.gz
myTestData_20140821_001.csv.g
myTestData_20140821_002.csv.gz
```

When I execute it, it retruns false for all files, if I replace

```
if [[ $line =~ ^myTestData_\d{8}_\d{6}_\d{3}.csv.gz$ ]] ; then
```

With

```
 if [[ $line =~ ^(.*)([0-9]{8})(.*)$ ]] ; then
```

It returns all files, means I am facing problem when using constant string in the regex, please point what is the mistake I am doing.

Thanks a lot !
Amit

Comment: _Match it_ and do what with it? It would be helpful to provide some context and ideally, show us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `\d` doesn't work in POSIX regex. Use either `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`.
2. In your question you said text is in the format of `myTestData_[YYYYMMDD][HHMMSS][NNN].csv.gz`, however the data in the CSV file doesn't contain the `[HHMMSS]` part. The regex you tried expects 8 digits followed by an underscore followed by 6 digits followed by an underscore followed by 3 digits. None of the lines in the CSV file matches this.

This regex matches the lines in the CSV file:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^myTestData_[[:digit:]]{8}_[[:digit:]]{3}\.csv\.gz$ ]] ; then
```

Comment: @AmitMittal Welcome to StackOverflow. The preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by accepting the most helpful answer (click on the green checkmark) to any question you ask (which also increases a bit your reputation too), and by up-voting helpful answers (if you have 15+ reputation).  Please read the [tour], and good luck with the answers.